# Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [128,128,4], [batch]: [128,128,3] [Op:IteratorGetNext]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to load a dataset to tensorflow, preprocess it and then creating batches to feed to a gan but for some reason some of the images has 4 channels!! Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [128,128,4], [batch]: [128,128,3] [Op:IteratorGetNext]

this is the function to preprocess data and then adding them to batch

```
    BATCH_SIZE = 32

 def map_images(file):
  img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(file))
  img = tf.dtypes.cast(img, tf.float32)
  img = tf.image.resize(img, size=[128, 128])
  img = img / 255.0
  reimg = tf.reshape(img, [128, 128, 3])
  
  return reimg

# create training batches
filename_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset/Damage type dataset/Damage type/Broken Glass/*.JPG")
image_dataset = filename_dataset.map(map_images).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by making channels parameter = 3 in tf.io.decode_jpeg, since it's default is 0 so making it equal 3 will force all the images to have only 3 channels